# image_path not recorded in database (laravel)

Tags: laravel, database, image

I have a problem in my web database, if I upload an image then the image path is not recorded in the database (the image path column is declared as nullable) whereas on the web it is marked that it has been submitted, here is the code from the controller that I have to handle uploading images on my website

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            // Simpan gambar di sini
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

            $report = Report::find($id);

            dd($report);

            $report->image_path = $imageName;
            $report->save();

            $report->image_uploaded = true;
            $report->save();

            return response()->json(['uploaded' => true]);
        }

        return response()->json(['uploaded' => false]);
    }
```

im expecting that the image path will recorded in the database

Comment: Your code stops/dies after `dd($report);` - nothing will be saved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, and the image name is being stored in your database instead of the path. But if you need to store the path, then you can use this approach

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            // Simpan gambar di sini
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

            $report = Report::find($id);

            
 // Concatenate base path with image name
        $imagePath = '/images/' . $imageName;

            $report->image_path = $imagePath;//store the path in the database
            $report->save();

            $report->image_uploaded = true;
            $report->save();

            return response()->json(['uploaded' => true]);
        }

        return response()->json(['uploaded' => false]);
    }
```

Make sure that the image_path column in your reports table is long enough to accommodate the full path, and update the column type accordingly if needed.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is what's stored in my database is only the name of the uploaded image, and the column for storing the image name is image_path. So when I upload an image, only the name of the image is saved, but from the code above, when I upload it, there is no data recorded in the image_path column, would you like to help me answer this?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't store the path `'/images/'` in the database, if you need to change that path later on (for whatever reason) you'd need to update all your database entries -  add/use the path in your templates/views

Comment: I get.Get rid of the dd() in your code and should work as expected.  
The dd() function in Laravel stands for "dump and die." It is a debugging function that is commonly used to dump information about variables and then halt the execution of the script. The dd() function is particularly useful for debugging purposes during development.

Comment: storing path in the database isn't a good approach and highly not recommended

Comment: what should i do guys, i have stuck with this problem for a week

Comment: Do you see the dd($report) in your code. get rid of it and your problem will be solved. Your script execution is dying at that place.

Comment: i have remove the dd($report) but the result is still same, there'no image path that recorded in database :(

Comment: I don't understand you now. You want image path stored in the database or the image name ?

Comment: "_storing path in the database isn't a good approach and highly not recommended_" But ...that's exactly what you did in this answer?!!

Comment: yeah, I thought you wanted to store the image path instead of the name. But the name is the one which is recommended

Comment: okay guys thank you so much for helping me, maybe i should ask my teacher about this problem

Comment: We can help, Personally i haven't understood what actually is the problem, At first i thought you wanted to store the image path. But not. Soo if your image name is being recorded in the database, then what exactly is the problem with the script or the functionality you wanted to implement?

Comment: can i message you through any platform for helping me solve this problem? if you dont mind, of course

Comment: Yeah, that is okay. linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/gideon-sipoi-6513911a3/

Comment: i have sent a connect request, please accept it :D

Comment: Please remove or resolve this question once you're done